# PHP function not displaying barcode using TrueType fonts

Tags: php, fonts, barcode

Hello I am using a function that I found in Internet to display a barCode using a TrueType font, here is the code:

```
//For displaying barcodes

//Arguments are:
//  code    Number you want outputted as a barcode

//You can use this script in two ways:
//  From a webpage/PHP script   <img src='/images/barcode.php?code=12345'/>
//  Directly in your web browser    http://www.example.com/images/barcode.php?code=12345

//Outputs the code as a barcode, surrounded by an asterisk (as per standard)
//Will only output numbers, text will appear as gaps
//Image width is dynamic, depending on how much data there is


header("Content-type: image/png");
$file = "barcode.png"; // path to base png image
$im = imagecreatefrompng($file); // open the blank image
$string = "123123123"; // get the code from URL
imagealphablending($im, true); // set alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($im, true); // save alphablending setting (important)

$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); // colour of barcode

$font_height=40; // barcode font size. anything smaller and it will appear jumbled and will not be able to be read by scanners

$newwidth=((strlen($string)*20)+41); // allocate width of barcode. each character is 20px across, plus add in the asterisk's
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, 40); // generate a new image with correct dimensions

imagecopyresized($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, 40, 10, 10); // copy image to thumb
imagettftext($thumb, $font_height, 0, 1, 40, $black, 'B2FI25HRc.ttf', '*'.$string.'*'); // add text to image

//show the image
imagepng($thumb);
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

I cannot find the error why the function doesn't display the image. Any ideas? The font is in the same directory with the php function and I tried relative and absolute paths to the font with no results. Any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Comment: you need to start doing basic debugging yourself. pretty much every GD function returns boolean FALSE on failure, but you never ever check for that. You simply assume nothing could ever fail. That's a bad way to go when dealing with "external" resources. Always assume failure, code accordingly, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for error messages.
For debugging, comment out the header line and add these lines on the top to show all errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In many cases the error messages will tell you pretty clear whats wrong.